# How large was a Byzantine administrative Bandon?

Tags: byzantine-empire

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandon_(Milit%C3%A4r)) states that in the Byzantine context a *Bandon* could denote a cavalry unit of 300, a military unit of 200-400 or an administrative unit. It further claims that originally the military and administrative unit coincided, but that they later diverged.

Does anyone know examples of how large these **administrative** units were? Are we talking about small cities with their surroundings (in which case a large percentage of relevant males were in the army) or something much larger?